# show logfiles on webserver

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have problem with showing txt.log document on my apache, using jquery. When i click button, txt file is shown. But logs are not shown good. Its just simple text area. I see all of the logs but they arent easy readable. How can i alligin the text, so every log line will be in own paragraph?

Background
I want to display error log from apache on my browser. With PhP i start bash script on server side, which copies log file from var folder . And with Jquery i show the copied logfile on my browser.

bash :

```
cp /var/logs/apache2/access.log myname.log
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#apachebut").click(function(){
$(".div1").load("apaccess.log");
    });
});
```

php script which trigers bash

```
<?php
      $message=shell_exec(" bash script 2>&1");
      print_r($message);
    ?>
```

css

```
.div1{
    weight:1500px;
    height:1500px;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:9px;
}
```

any suggestions, alternatives ?
thanks for help

Comment: Not sure whether it'll work but try using [nl2br();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: You will need to replace \t by spaces or you can echo log in <pre> tag.
\n should be seen as break in textarea

Comment: You can also use div with fixed width and height and overflow-y: scroll;
and pre tag inside him